# while loop not working only displaying one record when useing group by

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

I have a table (MySQL) where items might be duplicated (`room_number` and `menu_probelm` of row x are the same as `room_number` and `menu_probelm` of row y).  I am trying to only show row y if it is a duplicate of row x.  The table has 4 rows with the same `room_number` and `menu_probelm` values but col3 (`notes`) is different. For some reason it is showing me the 1st duplicate row(y) but not the other two.

Here's my code:

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT *, count(*) FROM damage GROUP BY room_number, menu_probelm HAVING count(*) > 1 ";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $hk) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
```

and here is the while statement inside my table:

```
<table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <th align="left" valign="top" scope="col">Record Number</th>
      <th align="left" valign="top" scope="col">Room Number</th>
      <th align="left" valign="top" scope="col">Room Number</th>
      <th align="left" valign="top" scope="col">Error Found </th>
      <th align="left" valign="top" scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
<?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top"><a href="#"><img src="../images/error2.png" width="25" height="25" alt="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['rid']; ?>"></a></td>
      <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['room_number']; ?></td>
      <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['menu_probelm']; ?></td>
      <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['notes']; ?></td>
      <td align="left" valign="top"></a><a href="delete.php?rid=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['rid'];?>"><img src="../images/Remove.png" width="25" height="25" alt="Delete Record"></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="3" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my SQL Tabel
|rid (ai) | room_number |menu_problem| notes |

 there are 5 records total.  Three of them have the room 135 with problem carpet they all have different notes and it is only showing me the first 1 record note the other 2 and what I want is to not show the 1st record but only the 2nd and 3rd (the duplicates ).
I tried to put the whole table in here in ACSSI but it looked a mess and I tried a HTML tabel, but it would not show it.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with your SQL query.  You are trying to do a `SELECT *` in your query, which is asking for **all** columns in the table.  But since you are doing a `GROUP BY` you can only `SELECT` the following columns: `room_number, menu_probelm`, and the `COUNT` of each group.

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT room_number, menu_probelm, count(*) AS 'frequency'
FROM damage
GROUP BY room_number, menu_probelm
HAVING frequency > 1;
```

The reason you cannot `SELECT` all columns in `GROUP BY` is that the MySQL engine has no way of knowing **which** value of those other columns it should choose for that group.

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I added it it and checked in in phpmyadmin and checked it with print_r($row_Recordset1); and I do see that the frequency (Count) is 3 like I want.  But it is only showing 1 record row. do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: The `HAVING` clause on the query will prevent groups with a frequency of 1 from being displayed.

Comment: I"m not sure we're on the same page here.  the SQL is telling me that the frequency is 3 like it should be.  But it is displaying only the 1st record (and it should be skipping that one and displaying record 2 and 3.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the table (if possible - you said it was only 4 rows) and the expected result.

Comment: @ tim the question has been edited to add what I could of the SQL tabel

Comment: There is no way to achieve what you want without modifying the query.  SQL will not discriminate between duplicate group members.

Comment: could you point me in the right direction.  As it is it will let me delete each record in tell there is only 1 left and at the point it does not show the record.